# Were there Roman "weekly executions" in Judea?

Tags: christianity, roman-republic

I'm down in the moderate unpleasantness that is the US state of Florida. Not having anything better to do, I pop down to the local amateur library and pick something out.

Most of it consisted of generic murder mystery novels, Except for Laurie Beth Jones's "Learn from the best; Jesus; Life Coach".

Despite being non-religious I went "Why not?" and picked it up. Interesting book. Not so much for the life advice, but for how the author writes about their religion and how they use it here.

Anyway, on page 17 (Chapter "Keep your focus"):

> Our guide, who was a Palestinian Christian, told us many tales we did not know prior to the visit. One of the most disturbing things he shared was that the Romans had a habit of crucifying people, especially Jews, every Friday. These "weekly executions" were meant to intimidate the Jews who where coming into Jerusalem because the people were hung outside the city gates for all passers-by to see.

Now, I'm no historian, in fact my profession is that of being a moron, but *I'm not convinced of that tale!*

I am aware that Jewish/Roman relations where mediocre at best, and there where crimes against humanity committed, but *weekly executions?* I mean, *come on,* that has "tall tale" written all over it. Perhaps a 20th century invention to "rev up" Christian tourists traveling to Israel?

Anyone know where this tale came from? No sources are listed in the book, and the tour guide isn't even named.

Comment: I'll see what I can dig up. I know their history with that method of execution is a lot bloodier than many people believe.

Comment: It was notable that in the Third Servile War, 6,000 rebels were crucified on one occasion. So a couple per average week would not seem outrageous. On the other hand, it is known that early sources greatly exaggerated the number of Christian martyrs.

Comment: "On the other hand, it is known that early sources greatly exaggerated the number of Christian martyrs." I was under a similar impression.